# $c$ primitive root, $a \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}, w/ j \in \mathbb Z^+, a \equiv c^j \pmod p), a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod p\implies j\text{ even}$.

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Suppose c is a primitive root modulo $p$.
Suppose you have a particular integer $a \in \{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ and you have found $j \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $a \equiv c^j\pmod p$. Show that if $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ $\equiv$ 1 (mod p), then j must be even. What does this tell you about the existence of solutions to the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$?

Comment: You must assume that c is a primitive root.

Comment: What is $c$? A primitive root mod $p$?

Comment: Oh right, C is a primitive root mod p. K fixed it.

Comment: I attempted:

$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} $$\equiv$ $c^{j^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}$ = $c^{\frac{j}{2}}c^{p-1}$ $\equiv$ $c^{\frac{j}{2}}$ as c is a primitive root and I want to show this is equal to 1 iff j is even. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: p=11, a=5, c=3 and j=3 
Wouldn't work since 3 is not a primitive root modulo 11 but it satisfies the other 2 conditions. Hmm..

Comment: If $c$ is a primitive root, what is $c^{(p-1)/2}$?

Comment: $\pm$ 1 = $c^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.
Oh okay and then that leave $c^j = 1$ iff j is even. Got it.

Comment: Which of the two, $+1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Er both are possible solutions to $c^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ as long as c is an integer not divisible by p.

Comment: I still have no clue what that implies for the existence of a solution to $x^2$ $\equiv$ a (mod p).

Comment: But $c$ is supposed to be a primitive root, not just any integer coprime to $p$.